# AngularJS $rootScope Issues

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Am using angular `$rootScope` to set two variables to use them to display whether user is logged in or not.

I have two functions

```
login() {
    $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
    $rootScope.username = response.principal.username;
}
```

and

```
logout() {
    $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
    $rootScope.username = "";
}
```

in my HTML I have something like

```
<div class="inline-divs" style="float: right" ng-show="isLoggedIn == true">
    <div class="inline-divs"><a>{{username}}</a></div>
    <div class="inline-divs"><a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></div>
</div>
```

The problem I have now is that the `div` appears when I log in. But when I click on the logout button (which calls the `logout()` function), that is suppose to hide the `div` again, it doesn't work. The `div` keeps being visible. I have other statements in the logout that successfully executed but I don't understand why I set `$rootScope.isLoggedIn` to false and the `div` doesn't hide.

What am I doing wrong

Comment: can you create a fiddle showing your issue ?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the `isLoggedIn` variable with `{{isLoggedIn}}` just somewhere on your page so you can see if it really is changing?

Comment: works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/jjro9cnk/

Answer (score 0):

Change these line

```
<div class="inline-divs" style="float: right" ng-show="isLoggedIn == true">
```

To

```
<div class="inline-divs" style="float: right" ng-show="isLoggedIn">
```

It is not necessary to check value for `isLoggedIn`. You can directly assign to expression as it is `true/false`.

Regards.

Comment: Alright then i would expect some fiddle from @Eddy, for case in which its failing.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="inline-divs" style="float: right" ng-show="isLoggedIn">
```

in ur controller before the log in and log out functions add this

```
$rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
```

and then check once in ur html page by printig the value so that u can able to whats happening with $rootScope.isLoggedIn

```
<pre>{{isLoggedIn}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had funny behaviour with the rootScooe in the html, try adding `$root.` before your variable, like this:

`ng-show="$root.isLoggedIn"`. You also don't need to explicitly check for true.